# Windows 8 Professional X86 on Internal HDD being reconized as a Windows To Go

Tags: windows-8, windows-to-go

I just clean installed a copy of Windows 8 Professional I got from Dreamspark academic. And when I got to the start menu it says that I shouldn't unplug the usb on my windows to go session.

Weird thing is this isn't a Windows-To-Go session. I am running the 32-bit Win 8 professional on a Dell Latitude.

How can I fix this?
I also can't use the Windows App store.

[image: In case you thought I had installed Windows 8 Enterprise]

Comment: Sounds like you installed Windows 8 Enterprise not Windows 8 Professional.  I would download the iso again and burn a new copy.  Windows-To-Go can only be created by an Windows 8 Enterprise installation.

Comment: No I have installed Windows 8 Professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to start screen and type regedit.

Mark the regedit tile (right click or drag it a bit down with a finger) and use the app bar button Run as administrator – confirm UAC prompt.

Within registry editor navigate in the left pane to key:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control**

Search in right pane the DWORD value **PortableOperatingSystem** and change the value from 1 to 0.

Reboot and look if this fixes it.

**Source:**
http://www.borncity.com/blog/2012/11/12/windows-8-a-cure-for-to-go-workspace-bug/

Comment: Wow, the cause seems so weird (conflicting device IDs)! MS really needs to release a patch for this ASAP.